# арифметические операции разных типов в mysql

Tags: mysql

Почему mysql возвращает странный результат:
'0.02' + 0.1 = 0.12000000000000001

Comment: "+ " - арифметическое действие, и чтобы сложить строку `0.02` неявно преобразовывается в `double`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте выполнить то же самое скажем в консоли javascript в браузере и вы получите тот же результат. Это происходит из за того, что mysql как и многие другие программы для работы с дробными числами используют [формат с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9) (который поддерживается на уровне процессоров).

Данный формат хранит некоторую часть мантисы и показатель степени, но на мантису отведено ограниченное число бит. Для представления большего диапазона чисел мантиса хранится не как есть, а пересчитанная по определенной формуле для обеспечения большей плотности на бит для небольших чисел и меньшей - для больших. Из за этого формат с плавающей точкой не позволяет хранить абсолютно точные значения, а дает их с некоторой погрешностью.